# Вопрос по задаче (C4) в ЕГЭ по информатике

Tags: c++

Считается ли мое решение эффективным по времени? Понимаю, что по памяти оно неэффективно, т.к используются структуры данных\контейнеры, а вот по времени не знаю как определить.

Условие задачи:

> С4 
>  По каналу связи передаются положительные целые числа, не превышающие 1000. После окончания передаётся контрольное значение – наибольшее число R, удовлетворяющее следующим условиям: 
>   1) R — сумма двух различных переданных элементов последовательности. 
>   2) R — нечётное число. 
>  
>   Напишите программу для решения поставленной задачи, которая будет эффективна как по времени, так и по памяти (или хотя бы по одной из этих характеристик).
>   Программа считается эффективной по времени, если время работы программы пропорционально количеству элементов последовательности N, т.е. при увеличении N в k раз время работы программы должно увеличиваться не более чем в k раз.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <conio.h>
#include <algorithm>

int main()
{
    std::vector<int> vec;
    std::vector<int>::size_type count;

    std::cin >> count;

    for (std::vector<int>::size_type i = 0; i < count; i++) {
        std::vector<int>::size_type current;
        std::cin >> current;

        vec.push_back(current);
    }

    std::sort(vec.begin(), vec.end());

    std::vector<int>::size_type maximum = 0;
    std::vector<int>::size_type left = vec.size() - 2;
    std::vector<int>::size_type right = vec.size() - 1;

    for ( std::vector<int>::size_type i = 0; ++i < vec.size(); )
    {
        std::vector<int>::size_type summary = vec[left] + vec[right];

        if ((maximum < summary) && (summary & 1 != 0)) 
        {
            maximum = summary;
            left--;
        }
        else { 
            if ((summary & 1) == 0)  {
                left--;
            }
            else {
                right--;
            }
        }
    }

    if (maximum) {
        std::cout << "\nFound: " << maximum;
    }
    else {
        std::cout << "\nNot found";
    }

    _getch();
}
```

Comment: А разве одна только функция `sort` уже не удовлетворяет поставленным условиям?

Comment: @zed вы правы. Когда писал, совсем не думал об этом. А что, если у меня в программе есть 2-3 цикла, но ни один из них не вложен в другой. Что при этом происходит со временем, исходя из критериев задачи?

Comment: Сумма времен этих циклов.

Comment: Если нету вложенных циклов, то время так и остаётся N.

Comment: Прямо в том цикле, где вводятся данные, сделайте всю работу. В ответе сказано, какую.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

После того, как вы вектор отсортировали, нет нужды в переборе. Вы должны взять наибольшее нечетное число плюс наибольшее четное. Сумма нечетная может быть, если одно число четное, а другое нечетное. Если нечетных нет, то и ответа нет. Не делайте сорт, который занимает nlog n, а просто ищите максимальное четное и нечетное за время n. Да, и хранить все данные в векторе не понадобится.

Comment: Большое спасибо. До вас не представлял решения без перебора массива. Может кому пригодится - https://pastebin.com/VN2Szr0k

Comment: Если нечетных нет, нужно выводить сообщение.
If(odd==0) cout <<"#$%%^^";

Comment: и так же выводит :)